# Taking specified number of user inputs and storing each in a variable

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am a beginner in python and want to know how to take just the user specified number of inputs in one single line and store each input in a variable.

For example:
Suppose I have 3 test cases and have to pass 4 integers separated by a white space for each such test case.
The input should look like this:

3

1 0 4 3

2 5 -1 4

3 7 1 9

I know about the split() method that helps you to separate integers with a space in between. But since I need to input only 4 integers, I need to know how to write the code so that the computer would take only 4 integers for each test case, and then the input line should automatically move, asking the user for input for the next test case.

Other than that, the other thing I am looking for is how to store each integer for each test case in some variable so I can access each one later.

Comment: I'd recommend using unittest library for tests. It's very simple to use, you'll not have any problem using it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, if you would like to store input in a variable, you would do the following...
    (var_name) = input()
Or if you want to treat your input as an integer, and you are sure it is an integer, you would want to do this
    (var_name) = int(input())
Then you could access the input by calling up the var_name.
Hope that helped :D